# Authorize access to controllers depending on Locked property added to ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorize-attribute

I'm migrating an ASP.NET MVC 5 project to ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET 5). In the previous project I had a `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` that checks if a user is locked o not (the first `else if (applicationUser.IsLocked)` statement).

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        ActionResult actionResult = filterContext.Result;
        int statusCode = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = filterContext.HttpContext.User.ApplicationUser();

        if (applicationUser == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserName()))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else if (applicationUser.IsLocked)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/home/unauthorized");
        }
        // If they are authorized, handle accordingly
        else if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise redirect to your specific authorized area
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/home/unauthorized");
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that this approach is not supported in ASP.NET Core, so I would like to know if it is possible to achieve this behavior and how can I develop it.

Edit:

Has you can see in ASP.NET Core 5 there is no `OnAuthorization()` method to override.

[image: AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core 5]

Comment: Which part exactly do you think is not supported in core? Custom attributes are certainly supported, is it the applicationuser properties that are giving you trouble?

Comment: The recommended approach is to define an authorization policy and annotate controllers/actions with `[Authorize("only_unlocked")]`

Comment: @BenMatthews I can't override ```OnAuthorization()``` method in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @Jon Not sure you need to. I think this answers your question and gives some great context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348219/1431405

Comment: Hi @Jon, you can inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute` and `IAuthorizationFilter` to implements your requirement. Remember that you should not set the `filterContext.Result` if the request is successfully authorize. Reference:https://stackoverflow.com/a/55113297/11398810

Comment: @Rena I edited the question, as you can see, there is no ```OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext)``` to override in ASP.NET Core 5.

Comment: Ok, there is no ```OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext)``` in AuthorizeAttribute. Maybe using IAuthorizationFilter?

Comment: Please read my suggestion carefully, I mean inherits from both AuthorizeAttribute and IAuthorizationFilter.

Comment: @Rena Ok, I understood. But what should I do with ```base.OnAuthorization()``` and ```this.AuthorizeCore()``` code blocks, delete them?

Comment: Hi @Jon, in asp.net core, just set `filterContext.Result` if the request failed, no need use `base.OnAuthorization()`.